# Creating SVG rectangle in React using mouse events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to convert a vanillajs/jquery example of using mouse events to draw SVG rectangles to a React component. Here is the vanilla js example:  [VanillaJS SVG Rectangles](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-rain-r8yl1) (click codesandbox refresh button is html doesn't display)

```
 import "./styles.css";
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgDoc;
var currentDrawing;
var startX;
var startY;
var offsetX;
var offsetY;
var isDrawing = false;

function init() {
  createSVGDoc();
  var position = $("#svgWrapper").position();
  offsetX = position.left;
  offsetY = position.top;
  console.log("offsetX = " + offsetX);
  $("#svgWrapper").mousedown(onCanvasMouseDown);
  $("#svgWrapper").mousemove(onCanvasMouseMove);
  $("#svgWrapper").mouseup(onCanvasMouseUp);
  $("#svgWrapper").mouseleave(onCanvasMouseLeave);
}

function createSVGDoc() {
  var imageWidth = parseInt($("#image").css("width"));
  var imageHeight = parseInt($("#image").css("height"));
  console.log(imageWidth);
  console.log(imageHeight);
  svgDoc = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
  svgDoc.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
  svgDoc.setAttribute("width", imageWidth);
  svgDoc.setAttribute("height", imageHeight);
  $("#svgWrapper").append(svgDoc);
}

function onCanvasMouseDown(event) {
  isDrawing = true;
  currentDrawing = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
  startX = event.pageX - offsetX;
  startY = event.pageY - offsetY;
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "x", startX);
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "y", startY);
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "5");
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "5");
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
  currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "5");
  svgDoc.appendChild(currentDrawing);
}

function onCanvasMouseMove(event) {
  if (!isDrawing) {
    return;
  }
  var wid = event.pageX - offsetX - startX;
  var hei = event.pageY - offsetY - startY;
  if (wid > 0) {
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "width", wid);
  } else {
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "width", Math.abs(wid));
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "x", event.pageX - offsetX);
  }
  if (hei > 0) {
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "height", hei);
  } else {
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "height", Math.abs(hei));
    currentDrawing.setAttributeNS(null, "y", event.pageY - offsetY);
  }
}

function onCanvasMouseUp(event) {
  if (!isDrawing) {
    return;
  }
  var wid = currentDrawing.getAttributeNS(null, "width");
  var hei = currentDrawing.getAttributeNS(null, "height");
  if (wid < 10 || hei < 10) {
    svgDoc.removeChild(currentDrawing);
  }
  isDrawing = false;
}

function onCanvasMouseLeave(event) {
  if (!isDrawing) {
    return;
  }
  svgDoc.removeChild(currentDrawing);
  isDrawing = false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});
```

Here is an attempt to rewrite the code using React: [React SVG Rectangles](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-cookies-snreu?file=/src/App.js)

```
    import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const initMouse = {
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0,
  startX: 0,
  startY: 0,
  isDrawing: false
};
const getElOffset = el => {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
    left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset
  };
};

const getCoords = e => {
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    return { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
  }
  return {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  };
};

export default function App() {
  const [drawings, setDrawings] = React.useState([]);
  const [mouseState, setMouseState] = React.useState(initMouse);

  const down = e => {
    var mouseCoords = getCoords(e);
    var offset = getElOffset(e.target.parentNode);
    const startX = mouseCoords.x - offset.left;
    const startY = mouseCoords.y - offset.top;

    setMouseState({
      ...mouseState,
      isDrawing: true,
      startX: startX,
      startY: startY,
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      offsetX: offset.left,
      offsetY: offset.top
    });
  };
  const up = e => {
    if (!mouseState.isDrawing) return;

    var wid = mouseState.width;
    var hei = mouseState.height;

    if (wid < 10 || hei < 10) {
      setMouseState({ ...initMouse });
    } else {
      setMouseState({ ...initMouse });
      setDrawings([...drawings, ...[mouseState]]);
    }
  };
  const move = e => {
    if (!mouseState.isDrawing) return;

    var currX = e.pageX - mouseState.offsetX;
    var currY = e.pageY - mouseState.offsetY;

    var wid = currX - mouseState.startX;
    var hei = currY - mouseState.startY;
    if (wid <= 0) {
      wid = Math.abs(wid);
    } else {
      currX = mouseState.startX;
    }
    if (hei <= 0) {
      hei = Math.abs(hei);
    } else {
      currY = mouseState.startY;
    }

    setMouseState({
      ...mouseState,
      startX: currX,
      startY: currY,
      width: wid,
      height: hei
    });
  };
  const leave = e => {
    if (!mouseState.isDrawing) return;
    setMouseState({ ...initMouse });
  };
  const renderManual = () => {
    return drawings.length > 0 ? (
      <>
        {mouseState.isDrawing ? (
          <rect
            x={mouseState.startX}
            y={mouseState.startY}
            width={mouseState.width}
            height={mouseState.height}
            fill="none"
            style={{ strokeWidth: 5, stroke: "black" }}
          />
        ) : null}
        {drawings.map((a, index) => (
          <g key={index} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
            <rect
              x={a.startX}
              y={a.startY}
              width={a.width}
              height={a.height}
              fill="none"
              style={{ strokeWidth: 5, stroke: "black" }}
            />
          </g>
        ))}
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        {mouseState.isDrawing ? (
          <rect
            x={mouseState.startX}
            y={mouseState.startY}
            width={mouseState.width}
            height={mouseState.height}
            fill="none"
            style={{ strokeWidth: 5, stroke: "black" }}
          />
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header" />
      <div class="lhn" />
      <div id="canvas">
        <div class="image" id="image" />
        <div
          id="svgWrapper"
          onMouseLeave={leave}
          onMouseUp={up}
          onMouseMove={move}
          onMouseDown={down}
        >
          <svg width="800" height="500" style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            {renderManual()}
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Everything appears to be working as expected until initiating mouse moves in the directions left and up. In this case the rectangles are not drawn. I'm having a difficult time understanding why the rectangles do not draw correctly when performing left and up direction mouse move events, but do so correctly in the VanillaJS example. Some extra eyes, and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code within the question itself, not as links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional state props (lastMoveX, lastMoveY) where needed so the original start x,y coordinates don't get overwritten. Here are the modifications:

```
   const initMouse = {
        lastMoveX:0,
        lastMoveY:0,
        width:0,
        height:0,
        offsetX:0,
        offsetY:0,
        startX:0,
        startY:0,
        isDrawing: false
    }
 const imgMouseDown = (e) => {
        var mouseCoords = getCoords(e)
            var offset = getElOffset(e.target);
            console.log(offset)
            const startX = mouseCoords.x - offset.left;
            const startY = mouseCoords.y - offset.top;
            setMouseState({...mouseState, isDrawing:true, lastMoveX:startX, lastMoveY:startY, startX: startX, startY: startY, width: 5, height:5, offsetX: offset.left, offsetY: offset.top})

    }
const imgMouseMove = (e) => {
    if(!mouseState.isDrawing) return;

    let state = {...mouseState};

    var width = e.pageX - state.offsetX - state.startX;
    var height = e.pageY - state.offsetY - state.startY;
    console.log(`w ${width} h ${height}`);

    if(width > 0){
        state.width = width;

    } else{
        state.width = Math.abs(width);
        state.lastMoveX= e.pageX - state.offsetX;

    }
    if(height > 0){
        state.height = height;

    } else{
        state.height = Math.abs(height);
        state.lastMoveY = e.pageY - state.offsetY;

    }
    setMouseState({...state})


    }
    const render = () => {


            return drawings.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                { mouseState.isDrawing ? 
                    <rect 
                        x={mouseState.lastMoveX} 
                        y={mouseState.lastMoveY} 
                        width={mouseState.width} 
                        height={mouseState.height}  
                        fill='none' style={{strokeWidth:5 ,stroke:'#009900', strokeDasharray:2 }}></rect>
                 : null }
                {drawings.map((a,index) =>
                    <g key={index} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                    <rect 
                        x={a.lastMoveX} 
                        y={a.lastMoveY} 
                        width={a.width} 
                        height={a.height}  
                        fill='none' style={{strokeWidth:5 ,stroke:'#009900', strokeDasharray:2}}></rect>
                    </g>

                )
                }
                </>


            ) : (
                <>
                { mouseState.isDrawing ?
                    <rect 
                        x={mouseState.lastMoveX} 
                        y={mouseState.lastMoveY} 
                        width={mouseState.width} 
                        height={mouseState.height}  
                        fill='none' style={{strokeWidth:5 ,stroke:'#009900', strokeDasharray:2}}></rect>
                 : null }
                </>
            )

        }
```